# problems using str.isnumeric() for printing a number from a list

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, numbers, lemmatization

im trying to build a function that receives a dataframe column,lemmatizes it and return only the numbers , for some reason im having difficulties with the str.isnumeric() method, whenever i try to use it i run into various problems ,i dont know what im doing wrong but i feel there's something in the method itself that i dont understand and havent seen anywhere written. the code is:

```
def lemmatization_sorting_func(line):
  
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
    wordnet_lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmas = (wordnet_lemma.lemmatize(w, pos = 'n') for w in words)
    lemmas=[l.lower() for l in lemmas] 

    if any(word in lemmas for word in game_years):
        for word in lemmas:   
            if x.str.isnumeric() ==True:
                return(word)
    else:
        return 'unknown'
```

and the error i get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-227-784ec2279a6b> in <module>
----> 1 df_new=Year_of_Release_nan['Name'].apply(lemmatization_sorting_func)
      2 df_new.value_counts()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4040             else:
   4041                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4042                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4043 
   4044         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-226-fd2134eee523> in lemmatization_sorting_func(line)
      8     if any(word in lemmas for word in game_years):
      9         for word in lemmas:
---> 10             if x.str.isnumeric() ==True:
     11                 return(word)
     12     else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1553             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1554             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".format(
-> 1555                 self.__class__.__name__
   1556             )
   1557         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Hard to say for sure without being able to reproduce. Where is the `x` variable coming from? It's hard to tell from your example and it doesn't seem like it's one of your for loop iteration variables.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MatthewBorish , oh , i see that this is an early version of the code, there simply change the 'x' with 'word':

Comment: my logic being that if the word in the lemmas list is a number then it will return true in the .str.isnumeric() method and then will print the word, yet it doesnt seem to work. my reasoning behind that is that perhaps this method is for different data type or something ,but couldn't really find anything on it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting the error without seeing your data, but I changed a few things around and this appears to be creating the output you're after IIUC.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')
import pandas as pd
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer

def lemmatization_sorting_func(line):
  
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
    wordnet_lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmas = (wordnet_lemma.lemmatize(w, pos = 'n') for w in words)
    lemmas=[l.lower() for l in lemmas] 

    for word in lemmas:   
        if word.isnumeric() ==True:
            return(word)
    else:
        return 'unknown'

Year_of_Release_nan = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['apple', '1992', '12', '2022', 'cat']})
Year_of_Release_nan['results']= Year_of_Release_nan['Name'].apply(lemmatization_sorting_func)
```

Year_of_Release_nan output:

```
    Name    results
0   apple   unknown
1   1992    1992
2   12      12
3   2022    2022
4   cat     unknown
```